# Changing glyphicon and image onclick

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

So I have an image with a glyphicon lying on top of it. On click, I want to change the image and the glyphicon. More clicking should just switch them back and forth between the two states. 
(imgA + glyphiconA <--click--> imgB + glyphiconB)

I used to have the image chaning on click working, but when I tried to add in changing the glyphicon with it, it began to have issues.

Currently, I can click the glyphicon and it will switch to the second image but the glyphicon won't change and upon further clicking it will not switch back to the original image.

NOTE: it's currently a one-image carousel, more will be added later so I need to keep this functionality with the fix

```js
var image_tracker1 = 'main';

function click1() {
  var image = document.getElementById('ImageButton1');
  if(image_tracker1=='main'){
    image.src = 'img/index-splash/1blur.jpg';
    $(a).find(".glyphicon")
    .removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom")
    .addClass("glyphicon-triangle-top");
    image_tracker1 = 'blur';
  }else{
    image.src = 'img/index-splash/1main.jpg'
    $(a).find(".glyphicon")
    .removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-top")
    .addClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom");
    image_tracker1 = 'main';
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<div id="mySplash1Mobile" class="carousel-splash slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=First%20slide" id="ImageButton1" width="100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="glyphicon-read-more" href="#mySplash1Mobile">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" id="ImageButton1" onClick="click1();" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
    <span class="sr-only">More</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You're probably having issues because you have two elements with the same id; `ImageButton1`.  That will give you some unexpected results.  Try using a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the onclick from the span and put it in the link tag itself. Like change

`<a class="glyphicon-read-more" href="#mySplash1Mobile">` 
to
  `<a class="glyphicon-read-more" href="javascript:click1();">`

And in your js, change

`$(a).find(".glyphicon")` to  `$('a').find(".glyphicon")`

Comment: So I tried implementing that and it sort of worked. It started chaning the glypicons in another area of the page (so i made it read $('a').find(".glyphicon-read-more") to work only in my area), but it never changed the glyphicon that I was clicking. The clicking now consistently changes the image between A and B, but not matter what glyphicon A is all that is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately fixed it by toggling rather than removing classes.

Javascript:

```
var image_tracker1 = 'main';

function click1() {
  var image = document.getElementById('ImageButton1');
  if(image_tracker1=='main'){
    image.src = 'img/index-splash/1blur.jpg';
    $('#GlyphiconButton1').toggleClass("glyphicon-triangle-top");
    image_tracker1 = 'blur';
  }else{
    image.src = 'img/index-splash/1main.jpg';
    $('#GlyphiconButton1').toggleClass("glyphicon-triangle-top");
    image_tracker1 = 'main';
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mySplash1Mobile" class="carousel-splash slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="img/index-splash/1main.jpg" id="ImageButton1" width="100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  a class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom glyphicon-read-more" href="javascript:click1();" id="GlyphiconButton1">
    <span class="sr-only">More</span>
  </a>
</div>
```